# Accessing a database initially to query user data

Tags: php, mysql

Probably a database and programming 101 question, but the few books I have read so far don't really explicitly touch on the subject.

When a user goes to a website and they need to login, there needs to be some user specified on the back-end somewhere that allows them to submit a query to the database to verify their information, correct?

The few books I have read on PHP and MySQL go into detail about verifying and setting up user verification, but they tend to have the username and password hardcoded into a separate file and then other files inherit it. This seems like a really bad idea.

They do eventually get into passing this information in with a variable that is assigned from the database query. But what they don't seem to say is that an initially user account needs to be setup that allows that query to happen. So it seems there should be a username and password hardcoded somewhere to make this initial query possible. Is this correct that there should be a username and password stored in a PHP file that is inherited for logging in purposes and then is replaced by the actual user info when they login successfully? If so, what permissions should that account have? Just `SELECT`?

I also ask because in poking around my company's website and looking at the PHP config file, there is a username and password hardcoded in it.

Comment: The credentials you use to connect to the database isn't connected to the user currently visiting your page.

Comment: The user to your website does not get credentials for your database. That would be bad design.

Comment: To elaborate, the username/password that is used to connect to the database is hard coded. It's always used to connect to the database. The users to the website don't "Query" your database. Your application/website does that. The user's information gets stored in the database like their username and a salted hash of their password (should they need one to log into your website).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All communication between in your case PHP and the database MYSQL is done by the same user, the user that is hard coded in a php file. like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

This is pretty secure because this file can only be accessed from within the server if you set the file permissions right (444 = read-only on Linux systems).

The verification on which users may access which page is application logic and has to be programmed separate and has nothing to do with the communication between PHP and the database.

If you need any further information please let me know.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. So basically all communication between the PHP and MySQL uses the same username, password, etc. that is specified in a separate file. The User table in the MySQL database would just be used to verify they are a user, what they have access to, stats, etc. The distinction is that username, password, etc. stored in the file is for database access and the web app user data stored in the User table is just for verifying the things I previously mentioned. That makes sense now.

Comment: @user3123109 your are correct, have fun programming!